# How can I pass the gradient of a tensor as a parameter in the loss function in PyTorch?

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, differential-equations

I am trying to implement a neural network in PyTorch to solve an ordinary differential equation (ODE). The network architecture is straight-forward. It is just a feed-forward neural network with `n` inputs and outputs and `k` layers.

```py
class PINN(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,n):
        super().__init__()
        # Layers
        self.L1=torch.nn.Linear(1,n)
        self.L2=torch.nn.Linear(n,n)
        self.L3=torch.nn.Linear(n,1)
        # Activation functions
        self.t=torch.nn.Tanh()
        self.r=torch.nn.ReLU()
    def forward(self,x):
        a1=self.r(self.L1(x))
        a2=self.r(self.L2(a1))
        a3=self.r(self.L3(a2))+x
        return a3
```

I want to minimize the loss between the gradient of the output of my neural network and the right-hand side of the ODE. I have chosen to work with a mean-squared error loss. I know that PyTorch includes a built-in MSE loss. However, I defined my own loss function since I have to pass in the gradient of a tensor.

```py
def ODELoss(x,y,x0):
    # Number of collocation points to sample
    n=len(x)
    # Initialize the loss to zero
    loss=torch.tensor(0.,requires_grad=True)
    # Loop over the "data". Technically, this is an unsupervised problem. 
    # The "data" are points sampled on the domain which are then evaluated
    # according to the ODE.
    for (xx,yy) in zip(x,y):
        xx=torch.tensor([[xx]],requires_grad=True)
        yy=torch.tensor([[yy]])
        g(xx,x0).backward()
        dg=xx.grad.clone().requires_grad_(True)
        loss=loss+(dg-yy)**2
    loss=loss/n
    return loss
```

Here, `g(x)` is called the *universal predictor*. It is used in the literature to account for the initial condition(s).

```py
def g(x,x0):
    return x*model(x)+x0
```

This doesn't seem to work because it seems like I am not passing in the gradient of the output correctly. Can anyone give me some guidance on how to do this?